# Inserting Columns to GridView dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview the page.. I added two columns!.. I didnt want to use the wizards to put data inside so I looked for some code over the internet that talks about feeding data dynamically to a gridview column Items..

I added some of the code if found and modified it to produce this:

```
         <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="תגובות">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Comments" runat="server" Text='<%# GetImage(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TicketReserved"))) %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>          
         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
       </asp:TemplateField>           
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="שם משתמש"><ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Image ID="imgButton" runat="server" 

           ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TicketReserved"))) %>' ></asp:Image>
       <br />
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetImage(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TicketReserved"))) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
```

The function:

```
 GetImage(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TicketReserved"))) %>
```

Is a dummy function that I want to swap with properties from my code.

Here the code behind and what it should do.

```
    List<ControlPanelMessages> allComments;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allComments = ControlPanelMessages.GetAllControlPanelPosts();
    foreach (var item in allComments)
    {
        Name=item.Name;
        Comment=item.Comment;
        Image =ResolveUrl(item.Img);
    }
}

public string Name { get; set; }
public string Comment { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }
```

This method:

```
ControlPanelMessages.GetAllControlPanelPosts()
```

returns a list with after all the sql statements to get text for the users name, users avatar and users comment were applied.

My question is how can I insert those 3 properties safely instead of

```
     GetImage(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TicketReserved"))) %>
```

I want the Gridview add items to columns till the foreach statement ends!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can put the values in a datatable and bind the datatable to the gridview.